# How to set CRUD methods on Sencha Touch 2 proxy/model/store/whatever?

Tags: database, model-view-controller, proxy, sencha-touch

I'm working with a partner to build a Sencha Touch 2 database app. He's built a ton of methods for me on the backend, with syntax like this:

- index.php?r=show/update
- index.php?r=show/add
- index.php?r=show/delete
- index.php?r=person/add

Each of which expects a POST to be sent with it.

What I'm struggling with is what the proxies should look like - for instance, is there a way to specify a show proxy that maps /update /add and /delete to their associated U/C/D actions? There's only one url in the proxy, and that is for the get action (getByUser in this case)

I'm assuming that I want to put the other actions into the proxy somehow - or do I just need a bunch of different proxies for each action (that seems kinda redundant...)

The Sencha docs imply that CRUD actions are built-in to proxies, but I don't see where or how their urls get defined...

```
Ext.define('SMToolkit.store.Shows', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

config: {
    model: 'SMToolkit.model.Show',
    autoLoad: true,
    sorters: 'name',
    grouper: {
        groupFn: function(record) {
            return record.get('type');
        }
    },
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'index.php?r=show/getByUser&username=FOO'
    }
}
});
```

With a model that looks like this:

```
Ext.define('SMToolkit.model.Show', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

config: {
    fields: [
        'id',
        'name',
        'opening',
        'closing',
        'rehearsal',
        'type',
        'availability'
    ]
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you should have a specific URL for each operation, ST2 provides you with the API property. You should change your proxy to:

```
proxy: {
   type: 'ajax',
   api: {
     create : 'index.php?r=show/add',
     read   : 'index.php?r=show/read',
     update : 'index.php?r=show/update',
     destroy: 'index.php?r=show/delete'
   }
}
```

Please note I removed the url property and added the api property. Also, to delete, you must enter the word 'destroy' because, in Javascript, 'delete' is a reserved word.